PhD in US after BA and MA in Europe
Did my bachelor and master in European universities (mediocre ones) and I did decent. Do I have a shot to apply for competitive PhD programs in US? How can I increase my chances? Are there like summer research programs through which I can meet professors?

See the answer for the US here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368. You will be treated like any other, but there is competition.
